# Calling Wow64GetThreadContext returns the error "When the file already exists, the file cannot be created."

Tags: winapi

I am using Wow64GetThreadContext calling from a 64bit process on a 32 bit process. I am catching the [WOW64 Context structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-wow64_context?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with this method.

The MSDN seems to no longer have the [documentation for this method available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-wow64getthreadcontext), it is however still referenced on the [GetThreadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadcontext) documentation page. I am not sure why this is. As the documentation is not available I am having a hard time figuring out why I am getting the error below.

The code where the error is being thrown is below. The error being thrown when I check GetLastWin32Error is: `When the file already exists, the file cannot be created.`

Does anyone have any ideas why it would throw this error? I am not creating a file at all which is confusing me.

```
ContextWow = new WOW_CONTEXT();
ContextWow.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FLAGS.CONTEXT_ALL;
try
{
    Wow64GetThreadContext(ThreadHandle, ref ContextWow);
    if (new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message != "The operation completed successfully")
    {
        throw new Exception("Win32 Exception encountered when attempting to get thread context" + new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you not check result of `Wow64GetThreadContext`. the `if (new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message != "The operation completed successfully")` is wrong and very strange code

Comment: You're making the standard error of calling GetLastError() without actually checking if the function failed. Additionally, checking an error code by comparing a language-dependent string is, as RbMm said, very strange code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the documentation you want, captured by the Internet Archive on July 10 2019:

[`Wow64GetThreadContext()` function](https://web.archive.org/web/20190710045120/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-wow64getthreadcontext)

Per the documentation:

> Return Value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Your error handling is wrong.  It is the equivalent of doing the following:

```
ContextWow = new WOW_CONTEXT();
ContextWow.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FLAGS.CONTEXT_ALL;
try
{
    Wow64GetThreadContext(ThreadHandle, ref ContextWow);
    if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Win32 Exception encountered when attempting to get thread context" + new Win32Exception().Message);
    }
}
```

You are making a very common mistake of calling `GetLastError()` at the wrong time. As the documentation says, the Win32 error code is valid to use only if `Wow64GetThreadContext()` returns false, which you are not checking for.

What you are doing is not the correct way to check for an error (either to get the error code, or to perform comparisons on it). The correct code should look more like the following instead:

```
ContextWow = new WOW_CONTEXT();
ContextWow.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FLAGS.CONTEXT_ALL;

if (!Wow64GetThreadContext(ThreadHandle, ref ContextWow))
{
    throw new Exception("Error encountered when attempting to get thread context", new Win32Exception());
}
```

That being said, the error message you are seeing, `"When the file already exists, the file cannot be created"`, is your system's text for the `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` (183) error code, which is not an error code that `Wow64GetThreadContext()` is documented as reporting on failure, and really just doesn't make much sense for this kind of function to report on failure. So, what is most likely happening is that `Wow64GetThreadContext()` is actually returning true, but because you are not checking for failure correctly, you are actually seeing an error code from an earlier/internal API call that has not been overwritten when `Wow64GetThreadContext()` returns true, and so it should be ignored in this situation, not acted on.